Organize React page with Material UI
I am new to React and Material UI. I'm trying to figure out the best practice for organizing my page layout. Right now, my components are one on top of the other vertically based on how I rendered them in the app file. I would like it look look more styled but not sure of the best practice for doing so. Please advice. Thank you
I tried styling the individual components with MUI flex box but all that did was move the components to the middle of the page but everything is still vertical:
<Component1 />
<Component2 />
<Component3 />
<Component4 />
<Component5 />

